# ionic angular can't install rxjs and image viewer - unmeet dependencies

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm trying to install rxjs and img-viewer for ionic, but it's always giving me errors. I post a screenshot of the shell for better understanding:

[image]

Both for rxjs and img-viewer it tells me that img-viewer need a peer of ionic-angular@3.8.0. I have version 3.9.2 of ionic-angular. This is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
"@angular/core": "4.4.3",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
"@angular/http": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "~2.4.1",
"cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.11",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
"ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.4.3",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
"ionic": "3.13.1",
"typescript": "2.4.2"
},
```

Why is telling me that? Maybe I have to downgrade to 3.8.0? How can I do that?Also, why rxjs@5.5.2 is saying that is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

ionic-img-viewer has been set up with a very specific version of ionic-angular (see the version given has no modifyer like `^` and no range like "ionic-angular@^3.8.0 || >=3.90 <4.0.0").

This means it would be better to downgrade to 3.8.0 to be safe, but you can try 3.9.2, but test it well. (Perhaps the changes between these two versions don't affect ionic-img-viewer).

To downgrade, install with `npm install --save ionic-img-viewer@3.8.0`.

I don't know why rxjs@5.5.2 is invalid, that was a valid release number. My approach would be to resolve ionic-img-viewer and perhaps the rxjs error goes away. If not, then try rxjs@5.5.3, and other versions. Try it independently to see if the message expands.

You can find out available versions and their release dates with `npm info rxjs`. For example, ionic-img-viewer is now on 2.9.0, so maybe that is the first thing you should try.

By the way, I use `yarn` as it's faster but compatible with npm. Start with `yarn install` to create the 'lock file'. Then most commands are similar, except `yarn add` instead of `npm install`, `yarn remove` instead of `npm uninstall`.

---

**After running a test install**

With the following dependencies, I had a clean install (using yarn and angular/cli).

Note the version of Angular is higher than yours, this is likely the fix for the rxjs error you were receiving.

```js
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
  "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
  "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.0",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.0",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
  "cordova-plugin-camera": "~2.4.1",
  "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.11",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
  "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
  "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
  "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
  "ionic": "3.13.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
  "tslint": "~5.7.0",
  "typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
```

Steps taken:

- ng new myproject
- manually added to project.json your dependencies not already present
- yarn install
- yarn add ionic-img-viewer

Comment: well, ionic-img-viewer is at version 2.9.0 while ionic-angular is at 3.9.2, so npm install --save ionic-img-viewer@3.8.0 is upgrading the img-viewer... am I wrong?

Comment: I believe `npm install --save ionic-img-viewer@3.8.0` will change it to that explicit version, so upgrades if currently lower, downgrades if currently higher. (Not sure if npm changes the `package.json` version after the change - I know `yarn` does).

Comment: If your'e concerned about compatibility between  ionic-img-viewer and  ionic-angular, npm should tell you if the latter needs changing (downgrading) as well.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that ionic-img-viewer is at version 2.9.0. (I don't see ionic-img-viewer in package.json). Let me do a test install, so I can get a clearer picture.

Comment: Hi, it tells me that  "No matching version found for @angular/core@^5.5.0" if running npm install

Comment: Interesting. What did you do to resolve it, compare package.json?

Comment: I've followed your steps and copied the package.json file, but running npm install give me the strange error. I wrote 5.5.0 so I'm not sure why it keeps saying that 5.5.0 thing

Comment: One factor that's missing from the steps I gave is that the version of Angular you get depends on the version of Angular/CLI installed globally. In your case, it gives you Angular 5.5.0 but my CLI is older so I get Angular 5.0.0. I'll see if I can figure out how to tackle it. Does the message indicate which dependency is looking for @angular@^5.5.0?